# Swift: Decode flat JSON to an structured object

Tags: json, swift, codable

wonder if there is a simple way to get a simple flat json to a struct with a structure

json:

```
 {
        "date": "2022-02-24T00:00:00.000Z",
        "personel": 800,
        "plane": 7,
        "drone": 6,
    }
```

what I want is to get a structure like this:

```
struct Day: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date : String
    var dayData: [DayData]

    struct DayData: Codable {
    var personel: Int
    var plane: Int
    var drone: Int
   }
}
```

I thought there should be some simple way to make it work

Comment: There is a way, you have to implement `init(decoder` and write the logic yourself. It's not that simple but it's not difficult either.

Comment: Your model does not match the JSON structure. There are a lot of posts how to work with JSON already.

Comment: I see a lot of init(decoder) implementations and they seem a bit too difficult, but I see that there's no other way

Comment: It depends why you need that different model. You could have a Decodable model which is the exact replica of your JSON, and use an Internal Model, that would look like your current one in your app. Just make an init/transformer between the two. The JSON model based on the API doesn't mean that the model you'll use everywhere else in your app are identifcal. That's the point of creating multiple layers (MVVM, MVC, VIPER, and others architectures).

Comment: That's exactly what I started doing, cause anyways I understood that I need to have a bit of calculated values etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in comments it would be better to create temporary `DBObject`  and initialize your `Day` object with it.

Simple DBObject:

```
struct DBObject: Decodable {
    let date: String?
    let personel, plane, drone: Int?
}
```

Adding `init()` to your `Day`

```
struct Day: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date : String
    var dayData: [DayData]
    
    init(from dbObject: DBObject) {
        let dayData = DayData(personel: dbObject.personel ?? 0,
                              plane: dbObject.plane ?? 0,
                              drone: dbObject.drone ?? 0)
        self.dayData = [dayData]
        self.date = dbObject.date ?? ""
    }
    
    struct DayData: Codable {
        var personel: Int
        var plane: Int
        var drone: Int
    }
}
```

Decoding Day from `Data` response:

```
func returnDay(from dataResponse: Data) -> Day {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let dbObject = try decoder.decode(DBObject.self,
                                          from: dataResponse)
        return Day(from: dbObject)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Cannot decode object")
    }
}
```

Comment: `.iso8601` cannot decode fractional seconds, you'll get `fatalError`.

Comment: @vadian thank you for pointing out, I changed it to `String` as was originaly in `Day` object.